# How can I display two lists with each li element vertically under each other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-lists

I have two separate lists (however I'm open for an example on how to just have one). The first list is information (such as 'title', 'length' 'release date') and the second list is the answers to the information (such as '50 Shades of Grey', '50 minutes' and '2015').

Here is my desired output and as you can see, the answers to the information is vertically centered under the information:

[image]

*(Note there could be more information such as members of the cast, the budget e.g)*

I have tried using `Flex` however the two lists are displayed separately on top of each other:

```css
ul {
   white-space:nowrap; 
}

li {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Title</li>
<li>Length</li>
<li>Release Date</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>50 Shades of Grey</li>
<li>50 minutes</li>
<li>2015</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You cannot do this with a list, or else you need to create 3 sets of `ul` with 2 `li` elements each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS table-layout for this. You have to set `display: table-row` on `ul` and `display: table-cell` on `li`. Also you should add `text-align: center` on `li`.

```css
ul {
  display: table-row;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Title</li>
  <li>Length</li>
  <li>Release Date</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>50 Shades of Grey</li>
  <li>50 minutes</li>
  <li>2015</li>
</ul>
```

You can also use `Flexbox` for this you just have to set `flex: 1` on each `li`. This will work if you have equal number of `li`'s in each `ul`, if not use table-layout.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Title</li>
  <li>Length</li>
  <li>Release Date</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>50 Shades of Grey</li>
  <li>50 minutes</li>
  <li>2015</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one method, using a single `ul` and flexbox:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

h2, p {
  white-space: nowrap; /* optional */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>50 Shades of Grey</p>
    <p>another title</p>
    <p>another title</p>
    <p>another title</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Length</h2>
    <p>50 minutes</p>
    <p>another length</p>
    <p>another length</p>
    <p>another length</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Release Date</h2>
    <p>2015</p>
    <p>another year</p>
    <p>another year</p>
    <p>another year</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to go hard-core semantic, you could nest the content of each `li` in another list, since they are also lists.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want each line to align even if content in one of the items would be higher, you need to have one (in this case) `ul` and then size the items so they wrap per, in this case, every 3.

To also make sure each item has the same width, I use `flex-basis`.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;       /*  create space between columns  */
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li:nth-child(-n+3) {                    /*  first 3 items  */
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

li {
  flex-basis: calc(33.333% - 10px);     /*  1/3 minus 10px for a gutter  */
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Title</li>
  <li>Length</li>
  <li>Release Date</li>

  <li>50 Shades of Grey</li>
  <li>50 minutes</li>
  <li>2015</li>

  <li>50 Shades of Black, and a longer text so it breaks line</li>
  <li>50 minutes</li>
  <li>2015</li>

  <li>50 Shades of Grey</li>
  <li>50 minutes</li>
  <li>2015</li>

</ul>
```